# Executing an effect inside an effect in ZIO

Tags: scala, functional-programming, effects, side-effects, zio

So I was writing a simple program in ZIO which would ask user its name and then simply greet him/her.

```
object PrintName extends App {
  val askName: ZIO[Any, Throwable, ZIO[Console, IOException, Unit]] = for {
    name: String <- ZIO.effect(StdIn.readLine())
  } yield (putStrLn(s"Hello $name"))
  override def run(args: List[String]): URIO[ZEnv, ExitCode] = {
    ...
  }
}
```

What should I write inside the run method so that I can execute the putStrLn effect?

Comment: Use `flatMap` directly instead of the `for` syntax.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez So I modified my code a bit and removed the PutStrLn statement from yield and now it's working. However, I wanted to know why the effect inside yield is not executed?

Comment: Why would it? It is just a value like any other, check the the _"Programs as Values"_ series to understand the paradigm: https://systemfw.org/archive.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 val askName: ZIO[Any, Throwable, ZIO[Console, IOException, Unit]]
```

Why do you have a type like that? It means that when the effect `askName` is run, it will produce another effect (that you would also need to run in order for it to have an effect; sorry for the pun).

You will want to use `flatMap` (or some variation of it, like the `<-` in a `for` comprehension) to combine the two effects.

```
val askName: ZIO[Console, Throwable, Unit]] = for {
    name  <- ZIO.effect(StdIn.readLine())
    _     <- putStrLn(s"Hello $name")
} yield ()
```

or

```
val askName: ZIO[Console, Throwable, Unit]] = 
   ZIO.effect(StdIn.readLine())
      .flatMap(name => putStrLn(s"Hello $name"))
```